# Setting a flag for mysqldb python

Tags: python, mysql-python

My goal is to prevent the "students" on my db to be changed unless the "teacher's" logs in first. I'm having trouble creating a flag that would do that.
function1 is for students and function2 is for teachers

What the flow i want is:

Teachers login first>flag is set to allow students to login>student logs in.

If the teacher has not logged in yet. The students cant. How do I do that?

```
import MySQLdb as mysql
one = 0
mydb = mysql.connect(host= "192.168.1.10", user= "XXXX", passwd= "XXXX", db= "XXXX")
cur = mydb.cursor()      
def function1():
  with mydb:
    receiver = raw_input("just waiting for an RFID: ")
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users")
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
      if(receiver == row[4]):
        cur.execute(" UPDATE users SET status= '1' where RFID =%s ",(receiver))

def function2():
  with mydb:
    receiver = raw_input("just waiting for an RFID: ")
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users")
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
      if(receiver ==  row[4] and row[3] == 1):
        cur.execute(" UPDATE users SET status = '1', status2= '1' where RFID = %s ",(receiver))
```